# PyQGIS Create Point Layer From Table Coordinate System reference

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis

I am trying to run "Create Point Layer From Table" processing tool.

```
processing.run("native:createpointslayerfromtable",
               {'INPUT':'C:\\Users\\ABC\\pointfile.xlsx|layername=Sheet1',
                'XFIELD':'POINT_X',
                'YFIELD':'POINT_Y',
                'ZFIELD':'','MFIELD':'',
                'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('ESRI:102080'),
                'OUTPUT':'C:\\Users\\ABC\\centroid.shp'})
```

This works fine if I run tool from within QGIS Python Console. However, if I run it from Spyder (which is properly connected to QGIS), python think that `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem` is a variable name and I am getting following error

```
name 'QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem' is not defined
```

Any other tool is working fine so it's not issue of link to QGIS.

Comment: Did you import it, `from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem` or `from qgis.core import *`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment by Kadir, adding

```
from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem
```

Solved it.